# How to use keras mask layer correctly?

Tags: python, nlp, keras, recurrent-neural-network

The Keras mask layer can be used to deal with variable-length sequence training of RNNs. When I use them I get lower accuracy with the mask layer than single batch training. I suspect that I'm not using mask layer correctly.

My goal is to train an LSTM to learn how to spell words. The sequences, which are different English words, are encoded with one-hot representation. Below is code of data encoding part: `chars` are the set of all letters that make up the sequences, `mylist` is list of the sequences, `MAXLEN` is the max length of sequences.

```
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

X = np.zeros((len(mylist), MAXLEN, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(mylist), MAXLEN, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)

for i, sentence in enumerate(mylist):
    for t in range(len(sentence)-Data_end):
        X[i, t, char_indices[sentence[t]]] = 1
        y[i, t, char_indices[sentence[t+1]]] = 1
```

My network is defined as:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, len(chars))))
model.add(LSTM(2000, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(2000, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars))))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=lr_init, decay=decay_init, momentum=momentum_init, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=2,verbose=1)
```

To train:

```
model.fit(X, y, callbacks=[early_stopping],batch_size=32, nb_epoch=1)
```

Am I using the mask layer correctly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is related to your problem but, shouldn't your `input_shape` in masking layer be `input_shape=(MAXLEN, len(chars)`?

Another quick observation, why is your LSTM having 2000 size state? Is that too large for a simple problem like this one?